# How to use css3 animations on svg object tags?

Tags: css, svg

I load a svg file into an object tag, and I want to animate it. I have a simple code here for a test, but there is a problem:

In my second css rule, I target `#main`, which happens to be the id of a `g` in side the svg element. I expect the `g` tag to animate, but it does not. If I replace the `#main` with `#svgA`, then it works. Does anyone know how to target contents of svg tags with css3?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>

        <style>
            /* The animation code */
            @keyframes example {
                from {
                    left:0px;
                }
                to {
                    left:100px;
                }
            }

            /* The element to apply the animation to */
            #main {
                position:relative;
                animation-name: example;
                animation-duration: 4s;
            } 

        </style>


    </head>

    <body>
        <object class="svgA" data="images/yeti/yeti-01.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put the CSS in the svg document. Pure CSS cannot be cross-document.

Answer (score 2):

Because the SVG is dynamically loaded you need to load the stylesheet from within the SVG itself. Try adding this to your SVG:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="anim.css" type="text/css"?>
```

Where `anim.css` is the stylesheet where your CSS3 animations are defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform to animate svg elements.

```css
/* The animation code */
@keyframes example {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
#main {
  position:relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <g id="main">
         <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
    </g>
</svg>
```